# Image not saving in UserProfileForm (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have a model form to update the user profile and everything is saving correctly except of them image. If I use admin it updates fine but when I use my form it just stays as the default profile image.

Here is my form:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):  
    birth_date = forms.DateField(label='birth_date', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            "image",
            "bio",
            "location",
            "birth_date",
        )
```

Here is my model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['created']:
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

Here is my view:

```
def edit_profile(request):
    instance = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()

            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

And here is my html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Edit Profile</h1>

<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Save</button>
</form>

</body>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For file upload you need to specify form's enctype:

```
<form method='POST' action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

And you should pass request's files to form instance in view:

```
form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
```

Check this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/) for details.